# How are "anded" 'if' conditions evaluated?

Tags: c#, if-statement

In C#, if we have the following code:

```
if (condition1 && condition2)
```

and condition1 turns out to be false, is condition2 still checked or does the execution simply continue after the if statement?

Comment: -1 No research effort. https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+%26%26

Comment: I edited your title to remove the tags. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for the reasoning behind that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly it evaluates `condition1`, then if it is `true` then it will evaluates `condition2`. It will not evaluate `condition2` if `condition1` is `false`. This is called [short-circuit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

No the `&&` operator is short circuiting. The `&` operator is however not and all of the expressions will be evaluated if you use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes C# does short circuit evaluation of boolean expressions.  Therefore

if ( X && Y() )

1) X will be executed first

2) Y will only be executed if and only if X returns true

This applies to all boolean expressions and not just those in an IF statement...Check this in the C# Specification available online at MSDN. section 14.11.1

you can use also the & and in this case it won't be a short circuite evaluation because

& is the "and" operator used for bit manipulation. 
&& is the "and" operator used to evaluate logically expressions.